# Adding a windows application in MVC web application solution

Tags: c#, windows, vs-web-application-project

I have a windows application. I want to add it to another MVC web application. 
I can migrate the windows application to MVC. But is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Add a new MVC project to your solution and start copying code over.  If you abstracted your business logic out and had it in separate assemblies this should be pretty trivial as you are just changing the UI/calling code

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is a bit too open-ended to actually answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints on how to improve your question. Please edit the question and we can try to help out.